# Activate and Deactivate the Rails code hyperlink using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

How to *activate* and *deactivate* the Rails code hyperlink using JQuery for the following code:

```
<%= f.add_associated_link "Add another email address",:class => 'add' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I you want to deactivate you could do something like

```
var activated = false;
$(".className").click(function(e){
 if(!activated){
   e.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

But you might wanna be a bit more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: I have tried with this part of coding but to my unluck it is not working please suggest other

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to hide/show the link? If so, you can use [toggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle).

```
$('a.add').toggle();
```

There's also [`hide()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide) and [`show()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show).